# Re - Is negative lookahead influenced by the amount of previous spaces?

Tags: python-3.x, python-re

Given the following regular expression:

```
import re
pattr = re.compile(r'(\d+\,\s+\d+\,\s+\d+\,\s+)(?!you shall not match\!)')
```

And the strings:

```
a = '1, 2, 3,      you shall not match!'
b = '4, 5, 6, you shall not match!'
c = '7, 8, 9, young neil asdfghj'
```

We see that:

```
>>> pattr.search(a)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 13), match='1, 2, 3,     '>    #With multiple spaces it does match 
>>> pattr.search(b)                                             #With a sinlge space it doesn't found anything; returns None
>>> pattr.search(c)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 19), match='7, 8, 9, '>
>>>
```

I would need to modify `pattr` in such a way that it returs `None` for **both** `pattr.search(a)` and `pattr.search(b)`, and return the same output as above for `pattr.search(c)`.

Any help would be frankly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why `a` matches but `b` does not is because the last greedy match for whitespace characters, i.e., `\s+` before `)` and the negative lookahead assertion, matches the longest *valid* match.

For `a`, this means that it matches one whitespace character less than what one would intuitively expect it would match. This means `1, 2, 3,` and 5 whitespace characters instead of all 6 that separate `1, 2, 3,` from `you shall not match!`. If it would match all 6, then it wouldn't be a *valid* match as you asked for `1, 2, 3,` followed by a series of whitespace characters not followed by `you shall not match!`. So, a match is possible and this what you get.

```py
>>> pattr = re.compile(r'(\d+\,\s+\d+\,\s+\d+\,\s+)(?!you shall not match!)')
>>> pattr.match(a)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 13), match='1, 2, 3,     '> # 5 whitespaces matched
>>>
>>> a
'1, 2, 3,      you shall not match!' # ... but a has 6
```

For `b`, things are simpler. You ask for one or more whitespace characters not followed by `you shall not match!` and there is no way to satisfy that if there is only 1 whitespace character between `1, 2, 3,` and `you shall not match!`. So, you get no match.

One possible update to your regular expression would be to add a word boundary (depending on your needs you may want to a. replace `\s*` with `\s+` or b. include `\b` inside the parentheses, i.e., the group):

```py
>>> pattr = re.compile(r'(\d+\,\s+\d+\,\s+\d+\,\s*)\b(?!you shall not match!)')
>>> pattr.match(a)
>>> pattr.match(b)
>>> pattr.match(c)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 9), match='7, 8, 9, '>
>>>
>>> # a and b do not match and c matches what it did with you regular expression
>>>
>>> pattr = re.compile(r'(\d+\,\s+\d+\,\s+\d+\,\s+)(?!you shall not match!)')
>>> pattr.match(c)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 9), match='7, 8, 9, '>
```

Another possible update would be to emulate an "atomic matching" or "possessive matching":

```py
>>> pattr = re.compile(r'(?=(\d+\,\s+\d+\,\s+\d+\,\s+))\1(?!you shall not match!)')
>>> pattr.match(a)
>>> pattr.match(b)
>>> pattr.match(c)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 9), match='7, 8, 9, '>
>>> # a and b do not match and c matches what it did with you regular expression
```

You may also want to check the [regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) that supports atomic grouping and possessive quantifiers.

Comment: I used `pattr.search` instead of `pattr.match` , but it's a fairly complete answer anyway. Thanks a lot! 